# Substitute names for IDs stored in two columns referencing the same table

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables:

- *table1*:

  ```
  id  no  name
  1   501  john
  2   354  sam
  3   201  anderson
  ```

  and
- *table2*:

  ```
  status  type      createdby  approvedby
  1       recharge     2         1
  1       topup        3         1
  ```

I need a query that would replace the *createdby* and *approvedby* references with corresponding names from *table1*, like this:

```
type           status           createdby         approvedby
recharge        1                 sam                john
topup           1                anderson            john
```

This is my attempted query:

```
SELECT `table2`.*, `tabl1`.`no`
FROM `table2`
JOIN `tabl1` ON `table2`.`createdby` =`table1`.`id`
JOIN `table1` `myTable` ON `table2`.`approvedby` =`orgTable`.`id`
```

But I am getting only *createdby* name, not *approvedby* name.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there.

First of all, your query contains what seems to be typos: there are two references to `` `tabl1` `` in it that should most likely be `` `table1` `` instead, and the `` `orgTable` `` alias should probably be `` `myTable` `` (or the other way round; my query below assumes the former).

Now with that out of the way, you can get the other name by referencing it via the `` `myTable` `` alias that you assign to the second instance of `table1`:

```
SELECT `table2`.`type`,
       `table2`.`status`,
       `table1`.`name`  AS createdBy,
       `myTable`.`name` AS approvedBy
FROM `table2`
JOIN `table1` ON `table2`.`createdby` = `table1`.`id`
JOIN `table1` AS `myTable` ON `table2`.`approvedby` = `myTable`.`id`;
```

Let me also note that your query will arguably be clearer if you use aliases for *both* instances of `table1`, as well as avoid excessive use of backticks:

```
SELECT table2.type,
       table2.status,
       creator.name  AS createdBy,
       approver.name AS approvedBy
FROM table2
JOIN table1 AS creator  ON table2.createdby  = creator.id
JOIN table1 AS approver ON table2.approvedby = approver.id;
```